# Lightswitch application gets stuck while getting latest changes from TFS source control

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-lightswitch, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have a Lightswitch application which was migrated to visual studio 2012 and TFS from Visual sourcesafe 2005.
When VS starts it is set to get latest version from TFS.

I get the current error message:
"**The item [Solution_name]\[Application_Name].vssscc could not be found in your workspace or you do not have permissions to access it.**" (I checked and it is indeed missing).
If I continue, the studio gets stuck.

If I delete the project entirely and get it again the solution loads OK, 
but any check in will cause the same phenomena to repeat.

Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

Comment: The problem was reproduced with a new Lightswitch project which was not migrated from old source control

Comment: Is the vssscc checked in to source control? If so delete it.

Comment: No , it isn't in source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was:
Some files were deleted, but the project reference to them was not removed in source control.
After removing the reference from the project and checking in, 
the problem was solved.